# Javascript to rotate between pages within ONE HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like some help displaying contents (to different pages) within one HTML page using JavaScript.
This is a sample of what I have found so far: http://www.swan10.nl/stuff/test.htm however instead of displaying "FAQ question #blabla" in the box every time a link is clicked, I would like to display words and images like a normal content. Is there a way to do this?

I tried removing the CreateDiv function and replacing it with HTML codes but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Umm, well you would need to use AJAX to pull the data into the page and display it in whatever method you choose. If you want to use a framework look into JQuery. It has nice AJAX functions. Otherwise read [HERE](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)

After re-reading your post I think you might just want to choose which div is displayed on a form at one time. This you can achieve by placing all of your divs in the same container. Then toggle their display css property.

Comment: There are some pitfalls in that example, but for what you are looking for I think this may be it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for!! Thanks! I'll try and make it fit my needs. Thank you again :D

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use the innerHTML property on one of your elements. It will allow you to add markup to that element. Check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Multiple DIV</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
DIV#db {  
  border : 1px solid blue; 
  width : 400px; 
  height : 400px; 
} 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var Content = new Array();
  Content[0] = '<i>test1</i>';
  Content[1] = '<b>test2</b><br><img src =http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogo.gif>';
  Content[2] = '<u>test3</u>';
  Content[3] = '<s>test4</s>';

function Toggle(IDS) {  
  document.getElementById('db').innerHTML = Content[IDS];
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="Toggle(0,10)"> 
<a href='#' onClick="Toggle(0)">FAQ #1</a> 
<a href='#' onClick="Toggle(1)">FAQ #2</a> 
<a href='#' onClick="Toggle(2)">FAQ #3</a> 
<a href='#' onClick="Toggle(3)">FAQ #4</a> 
<p /> 
<div id="db"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I updated it to work all javascripty with the innerHTML

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I'll give this a try! However I still would like to know how to do this using JavaScript. Thanks :)

Comment: I used your test site and changed it around to show you how you can use the innerHTML and javascript to make it a little tighter than hiding/showing divs. This will give you a little less overhead

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery it's as simple as

```
$('#divname').load('/path/to/file.html');
```

Note that the result should probably not include `<html>` and `<head>` tags (although you don't seem like you care about well formed HTML code).

I should probably also mention that you shouldn't make the client load content for you, that's what server side code is for.

Comment: On the contrary, I am very specific when it comes to coding - clean coding + XHTML (which means well formed HTML code).

As said above, it is a test code and it's a code I found from a different website. I tried it but didn't manage to change the display from "FAQ question #blabla" to the content that I want so I just copied the code to show it as a website and posted the question.

Nonetheless, thanks for your help.