# Toggling for Live Webpages

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a project at my internship where we are trying to create some kind of display that shows live status updates of our servers. I have the webpages I need to use on file; however, I am very confused on how to code the display. We are planning to use HTML and JavaScript, so I have been able to find these links. Are they leading me down the right path?

[Javascript to rotate between pages within ONE HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275673/javascript-to-rotate-between-pages-within-one-html-page)

https://www.wikihow.com/Toggle-HTML-Display-With-JavaScript

Still, I am not sure how to add the links in there as well as if/how to write the CSS.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "I have the webpages I need to use on file" What does that mean ?

Comment: A quick layout example would help here. Are you saying you want to change the page on a link click?

Comment: @Seblor That means I have the links and access to the sites I want to use in the project.

Comment: @DanielD I just want the pages to appear in full on the website as they are in real-time and toggle between them at a rate of perhaps 60 seconds.

Comment: You could use an iframe and make a rotation, using a `setInterval()` for changing the `src` attribute of said iframe

Comment: @Seblor Is that for the HTML, JavaScript, or CSS? (Sorry, but I am rather new to this.) Also, how would that reflect in the other aspects of my code?

Comment: I described the whole thing... iframe is an HTML element. `setInterval()` is a JS function (look it up on the MDN (the JS documentation). As to your last question, I have no idea since I do not know what you want / need. Not wanting to sound rude, but you should not expect us to do what is litterally your job (as an intern in a company), you should try with your own knowledge, not crowd-source it.